# Track Bandwidth on shared interface

Tags: linux, centos7, linux-networking, freebsd, network-monitoring

On our servers running FreeBSD, we've allocated multiple public ip addresses to host different clients on single `eth0` interface. The purpose of allocating separate ip to each client is to distinguish their traffic from one another.

Now the problem is, as each of our clients is using separate ip but interface/port is same due to which monitoring tools like `nload` and `iftop` are only able to track cumulative interface bandwidth and to track how much bandwidth each client is consuming we need to calculate bandwidth usage based on public ips that are allocated to each client. Please suggest some tools or ways of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Elastiflow on ELK backed with sflow/netflow helped us achieve the goal, it gives every ip bandwidth usage information with absolute time period mentioned. In addition to that, it gives very useful packets traversing information to have top overview of the infrastructure if configured on core switches.

[ElastiFlow](https://github.com/robcowart/elastiflow)